# .htaccess rewrite path: New query string removes the paths first trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have this code to rewrite a path, and then redirect to subdomain's folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/?$ category.php
RewriteRule ^category/[a-z0-9\-]+\_([A-Z0-9\_]+)/?$ articles.php?id=$1&section=category

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.(.*)example.com/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\!test/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /!test/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

The big problem is that typing this in the browser address field and press Enter:

```
http://test.example.com/category/article-about-something_35436
```

Ends up in that it changes by itself to:

```
http://test.example.comcategory/article-about-something_35436
```

And the browser of course tells you that "Server is not found".

**Troubleshooting**

I have figured out that this works fine:

```
http://test.example.com/category
```

And removing the query string `?id=$1&section=category` from the second rewrite rule works. You don't end up on the article of course but on `articles.php`.

So, anyone know the problem?

Comment: Open Firebug and visit `http://test.example.com/category/article-about-something_35436` in browser. Now see what redirects you get in `Net` tab.

Comment: Got nothing there, just empty. But in Chrome's developer tool's network section theres happening things. But I can't see anything that tells me what to do. I see a "301 Moved Permanently".

Comment: Right when you get 301 what does it get redirected to? Also you code doesn't have any 301

Comment: Sorry, I have a 301-redirect last in the file that I didn't thought was needed because of the R flag. I have edit the question now, you can see. The 301-redirection in Network is to `test.example.comcategory/article-about-something_35436`. And the status for that row is `"(failed) net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"`. What's interesting is that it's presented in both rows like path's `category` is part of the domain and not the path.

Comment: Sorry, meant L flag in the first sentence in the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your rules and keep redirect rules with `R` flag before other internal rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^category/?$ category.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/[a-z0-9-]+_([A-Z0-9_]+)/?$ articles.php?id=$1&section=category [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.(.*)example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\!test/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /!test/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Did you test in Chrome dev tool by entering URL as `http://test.example.com/category/article-about-something_35436` in browser? There is no 301 for that URL in your rules

Comment: Yes, I did. And no, there isn't. That's why this is so strange. :/

Comment: Signing off now, you can check Apache server config also for some rules or may be our code.

Comment: This is embarrassing. The problem was a 301 redirect in the php code. The fact that you several times pointed out that it's actually must be a 301 redirection somewhere did me look there. So, we say you solved this :)

Comment: Oh great to know you got it resolved. If you think my answer helped you you can mark the answer as accepted :)